# find command with dynamic binding variable is not working for remote server

Tags: linux, sh

I'm trying to generate checksums for all files that are present in a directory on a remote system using the following code:

```
ssh  root@$host1 'find /foo/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + >/tmp/checksum.txt;'
```

File `/tmp/checksum.txt` is created in remote host and contains the generated checksum for each file.

I tried the same command with a variable instead of hardcoding source and destination. Then the file `checksum.txt` is not created in remote host.

```
export src=/foo
export dest=/tmp/checksum.txt

ssh  root@$host1 'find $src -type f -exec md5sum {} + >$dest;'
```

I tried the below command in my local machine with a variable, it is generating the output file in the `$dest` path.

```
find $src -type f -exec md5sum {} + >$dest;
```

I have this issue only with the remote system. What is the reason it is failing to create file only for remote server with a dynamic variable?

Comment: Single quotes block envVar expansion. Use dbl-quotes, i.e. `ssh "cmd $var > $varr2"` . Voting to close as a typo. Good luck.